# Deleted question used as a review audit

Tags: bug, review-audits

I just received a review audit that used a deleted question (the question is really deleted), https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/7784760. Screenshot of before I have taken any action:

[image: review edit shown as deleted]

Out of curiosity I selected close, which failed the audit (the question received 7 upvotes before it was deleted by the TS).

Although it might have been a fine question, the fact it was deleted should have excluded it from the review audit.

Comment: I wonder why it was flagged as "_Primarily opinion based_". I don't see anything opinion based here.

Comment: @JonasCz As this is a review audit, it is - in my experience - pretty random which close reason it shows. That is not my point though. A deleted question is IMO a poor choice for a review audit, having that review audit render the question as deleted is worse. It might deter you from looking closely at the question (it is deleted, so Close is probably the right choice). Which is also why I intentionally chose Close: to see what happened.

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: "Doctor, should we try to save this patient?" "Well, he's dead." "Well, yes, now he is.  Aside from that, should we have tried to save him?  Could he have been viable?" "We'll never know, will we..."

Comment: Seven up votes on that question and zero down votes, in less than 24 hours? Seems a little fishy.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I agree, if I hadn't noticed that it was review audit, I probably would have voted to close anyway for lacking the full code to reproduce (especially how that decimal is derived). People probably upvoted because they thought it an interesting problem.